# How to find all fields being used in my Crystal Reports from SQL?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm trying to clean up my SQL database and find out which fields are not being used. Is it possible to find all fields from SQL that are being used in Crystal Reports without manually looking in each query?

Thank you!

Comment: As a followup, I wanted to find fields that are also being used as conditionals such as WHERE, CASE WHEN, etc. Thank you! :)

Comment: Please provide what SQL database you are using and elaborate on your requirement.

Comment: You could could PowerShell and the Crystal Reports SDK to do something like this.  [PsCrystal](https://github.com/craibuc/PsCrystal) is a good starting point.

Comment: I am currently using SQL Server Management Studio. I'm trying to create a report to see which fields are being used in which reports, so I'm just trying to pull fields from queries without manually searching throughout the query.